# How to get image source attribute inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple image directive like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';    
    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .directive('imageTest', imageTest);
    function imageTest() {
        var directive = {
            'link': link,
            'restrict': 'A',
            'scope': {}
        };

        return directive;
    }

    function link($scope, element) {
        var src = element.src;
        console.log(src) => undefined
        // code to modify src
    }

})();
```

html

```
<img id="image" ng-src="{{myImg.url}}" image-test/>
```

All i need is to get image src attribute inside the directive but I can't seem to find out how to do it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What shows in console.log when you just log 'element'? Can I see?

Comment: please check whether you are getting the "element" in "element.src" that may be returning undefined.because you don't seem to have passed the "element" parameter into the link function here "'link': link"

Comment: I don't know how much this is correct, but sometimes I get to use $timeout and check the value

Comment: In line _var src = element.src;_ _element_ point to jQLite (jQuery) object. Try change to _var src = element[0].src_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attribute there is an expression, which will evaluate after instantiation of the directive. You can use $observe to get the value:

```
function link($scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function(url) {
        console.log(url);
    });
}
```